# AddColumn String with Default Value in MigrationTable DbFlow

Tags: android, dbflow

Can anyone please tell me how can I add the default value to the Migration table. I am using the following class:

```
@Migration(version = PictureDatabase.VERSION, databaseName = PictureDatabase.NAME)
public class MigrationPicture extends AlterTableMigration<Picture> {
    public MigrationPicture() {
        super(Picture.class);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPreMigrate() {
        // Simple ALTER TABLE migration wraps the statements into a nice builder notation
        super.onPreMigrate();
        if(PictureDatabase.VERSION == 2) {
            addColumn(String.class, Picture$Table.PICTURETYPE);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.